# Как правильно пишется: "гаргулья" или "горгулья"?

Tags: орфография

Мне в текстах попадалось и "гаргулья", и "горгулья". А как правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Однозначно ответить нельзя.
Слово пока не фиксируется нормативными словарями. В специальных источниках действительно используются оба написния. Вариант "гаргулья" более оправдан французским источником, но фонетически ещё ближе "гаргуйль", тоже иногда используемый. Но это все равно не совсем соответствует французскому произношению (еще ближе было бы "гаргуий"), так что это тоже не аргумент.

Answer (score 0):

Можно подумать "гАргулья" это в каких-то "нерусских текстах". Откуда вообще там "о" может взяться? Наверное, оттуда же, откуда лабутены и куршавели. "Горгулья" звучит столь же глупо, как и "Дарк Вадор" (это так для французов звучит имя Дарта Вейдера, видимо тоже "максимально близкое по звучанию").